# test for page content fails but should succeed, minitest, capybara, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I am slowly teaching myself testing with minitest.  I cannot figure out why this test is failing because the page DOES include the content I am searching for:

```
require "test_helper"

class CustomerViewsTest < Capybara::Rails::TestCase
  def test_aboutpage_has_content
    # visit '/customer/about'
    visit customer_about_path
    assert page.has_content?("Those creatures are sly little devils")
  end
end
```

I receive the following error: `Minitest::Assertion: Failed assertion, no message given.`

The page exists, the path is correct, I've checked the spelling, and the page includes that content.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have other tests that are passing using this stack?

Comment: How do you know the page does include the contents?  Have you output page.html to the screen?  Also what driver are you using with capybara?

Comment: Try using something like ruby-debug or pry to step into your code and print the contents of the page. Make sure that you're actually getting the content.

Comment: Is the content being rendered via JS?  If so that is your problem.  If you install the launchy gem you can add save_and_open_page and see the page as it sits when the test hits it.  I am not very familiar with minitest but rSpec usually gives a more helpful error that includes the visible text on the page.

Comment: @ruby_newbie It's not giving a detailed message because  has_content? swallows the error to return a boolean -- using page.assert_text("Those creatures are sly little devils")  instead would provide a more detailed error message

Comment: Is the content being rendered via javascript?  did you try launchy?